# How do I populate an array with get-process results in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PS1 script that:
1. takes a computer name and a process name
2. Shows you all PIDs and processes that match your search
3. Asks you what PID you want to kill. (I haven't included this part of the code)

I need help on the $processInfo array. 
I want to be able to look through each of the processes and show the name and ID. and then I'll know what PID to kill after that.

So if I search "App*" how can I output to the format of:

```
Process ID: 1000 Name: Apple
Process ID: 2000 Name: Appster
Process ID: 3000 Name: AppSample
```

Here's what I have so far

```
# Look up a computer, and a process, and then 
$computerName = Read-Host "Enter the FQDN of the target computer:"

# Enter the name of the process you're looking for. Wildcard searching is asterix
$processSearch = Read-Host "Enter the process name to look for:"

# Create a process array with PID, Name, and Runpath
$processInfo = (
    processID = get-process -ComputerName $computerName -Name $processSearch | select -expand ID,
    processName = get-process -ComputerName $computerName -Name $processSearch |select -expand Name,
    processPath = get-process -ComputerName $computerName -Name $processSearch |select -expand Path
)

# Display all of the processes and IDs that match your search
foreach($id in $processInfo){
    write-host Process ID: $id.processID Name: $id.processName
}
```

Comment: Don't call `Get-Process` multiple times.   Call it once and save the result - it's already an array.  Then have your foreach go through each object.   Better yet, try this:   `$process = Get-Process -ComputerName $computerName -Name $processSearch | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single`.  Or do what @BenH suggested.

Comment: You don't need to expand them to have all the details. Something like `$processinfo = get-process -ComputerName $computername -name $processsearch | select id,name,path`.  Also please change write-host to write-output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-Process` can take wildcards in the `Name` parameter. So you just need to loop over the object and output the properties you are looking for.

```
# Look up a computer, and a process, and then 
$ComputerName = Read-Host "Enter the FQDN of the target computer:"

# Enter the name of the process you're looking for. Wildcard searching is asterix
$ProcessSearch = Read-Host "Enter the process name to look for:"

Get-Process -ComputerName $ComputerName -Name "$ProcessSearch*" | ForEach-Object {Write-Host Process ID: $_.ID Name: $_.ProcessName}
```

You could also [get rid of all of the `Read-Host` and `Write-Host`](https://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/) for a more PowerShelly feel.

```
Get-Process -ComputerName $ComputerName -Name "$ProcessSearch*" | Select-Object ID,ProcessName
```